# jQuery 1.3.2 and IE 8 problem with hide() and show()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, hover, hide, show

Can someone tell me please why the following example work in Firefox but not in IE 8?
Only content_1 work correct in IE 8.

Thx vijey.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $("#sortable").sortable({handle: '#dragable'});
});


$(function(){

   var v;

  $('div[id^="content_"]').hover(

        function () {

        v = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#'+v+' #menu').show();
            $('#'+v+' #dragable').show();
        },
        function () {
            $('#'+v+' #menu').hide();
            $('#'+v+' #dragable').hide();
        }
    );

});

</script>


<body>

<div id='sortable'>

    <div id='content_1'>

        <div id='menu' style='display:none;'>
            <div>edit</div>
            <div>add</div>
            <div>delete</div>
        </div>

        <div id='content'>Content_1</div>

        <div id='dragable' style='display:none;'>[drag]</div>
    </div>




    <div id='content_2'>

        <div id='menu' style='display: none;'>
            <div>edit</div>
            <div>add</div>
            <div>delete</div>
        </div>

        <div id='content'>Content_2</div>

        <div id='dragable' style='display:none;'>[drag]</div>
    </div>





    <div id='content_3'>

        <div id='menu' style='display: none;'>
            <div>edit</div>
            <div>add</div>
            <div>delete</div>
        </div>

        <div id='content'>Content_3</div>

        <div id='dragable' style='display: none;'>[drag]</div>
    </div>

</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs must be unique within a page (html spec [1]); you have 2 `#menu`, `#content`, etc. Change them to e.g. `<div class="menu">` and your selector to `.menu` -- that should work.

Incidentally, you can simplify your hover callback with `find` [2]:

```
function () {
    $(this).find('.menu, .dragable').show(); 
}
```

1: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2
2: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID, it's invalid HTML, IDs have to be unique.  Your menu elements needs to be a class instead of an ID, like this:

```
<div id='content_1'>

    <div class='menu' style='display: none;'>
        <div>edit</div>
        <div>add</div>
        <div>delete</div>
    </div>

    <div class='content'>Content_2</div>

    <div class='dragable' style='display:none;'>[drag]</div>
</div>
```

And jQuery like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('div[id^="content_"]').hover(
        function () {
          $(this).find('.menu, .dragable').show();
        },
        function () {
          $(this).find('.menu, .dragable').hide();
        }
    );
});
```